Reassign CIDR blocks to subnets during CFN stack update
I have a CFN stack for my VPC where I first create only public and private subnets, which get assigned default CIDR blocks. Now after a while I need to add isolated subnets to the VPC as well. When I try to update the CFN stack, I get an exception - "The CIDR '10.0.0.0/25' conflicts with another subnet
Is it possible to reassign the CIDR blocks to the subnets after adding more subnets in CFN stack update?
Here's sample code:

    if (<some condition>){
        this.createVpcWithIsolatedSubnets();
    } else {
        this.createVpc() 
    }

createVpc() {
    const vpc = new ec2.Vpc(this, `VPC`, {
        maxAzs: MAX_AZ,
        subnetConfiguration: [
           {
               name: 'Public',
               subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC
           },
           {
               name: 'Private',
               subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_WITH_EGRESS
           }
        ]      
   });
}

createVpcWithIsolatedSubnets() {
            
    const vpc = new ec2.Vpc(this, `VPC`, {
        maxAzs: MAX_AZ,
        subnetConfiguration: [
           {
               name: 'Public',
               subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC
           },
           {
               name: 'Private',
               subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_WITH_EGRESS
           },
           {
               name: 'Isolated',
               subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_ISOLATED
           }
        ]      
   });
}


I found this https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/28369 which is a similar problem but there is no answer to suggest how to go about this issue. Basically how does a CDK update, change the VPC itself.

The error indicates you are trying to add a new subnet with a CIDR that overlaps with one that already exists.  In your CloudFormation template, when creating subnets you can specify the CIDR range to use.
Also, the documentation for the CIRD property of a subnet mentions that

If you update this property, we create a new subnet, and then delete
the existing one.

So most likely you are trying to take an existing subnet CIDR and reduce it to something smaller while also adding a new subnet that uses part of the same range.  This will cause overlap since CloudFormation will try to make the new subnets first and will only delete the old one during the cleanup phase.  You would need to delete the existing subnet in a stack update, then create two new ones with smaller CIDR ranges in a subsequent stack update that runs after the first update has finished.
It isn't possible to "reassign the CIDR blocks to the subnets" since an update really means deleting the existing one and recreating a new one.  Also see subnet sizing.  If you can post the relevant parts of the original CFN template and the new one it would be easier to compare to see what CIDRs you are using for the subnets.

Thanks for the answer! I didn't mention any CIDR blocks currently for the VPC subnets, assuming that the VPC will automatically assign it based on the number of subnets that are there.

I have a follow up question, when you say that - since an update really means deleting the existing one and recreating a new one does it identify a stack by its id? Because we never mention update operation in ts in cdk, we always mention create so does it by default find the stack by its ID?

This addresses how the CDK identifies the stack: https://repost.aws/questions/QUqu7hQqTzT92XX0MM4nVe4A/cdk-how-do-i-update-a-stack-resources-in-cdk-without-duplicating-them  It sounds like you may need to specify the subnet CIDR using the cidrBlock construct prop  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ec2.Subnet.html
